# Newbie: How do I make my cube transparent?

Tags: transparency, glass

first time posting. Absolutely loving Blender.

I have had success tracking a cube into a video of my living room wall. I'd like to try turning it into glass but when I turn the transmission to 1, I don't see the background through the cube. Here's my screenshot:

[image]

I've tried to search for specifics on this but not had any luck. Time to ask the hive, as I'm sure it's very simple. Any tips?
Thanks!

Comment: if you are in Eevee, in the Material panel > Settings, you need to choose Blend Mode > Alpha Blend

Comment: This clearly looks like Cycles, try turning your roughness to 0. Also, be sure the base color is fully white.

Comment: at the very bottom right of your screen shot, "Use Transparency" is not selected.  What happens when yo select it?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I posted this question when I didn't know about camera projection, which is what I'd need to create a transparent object reacting to a background. cheers.